# What's the wrong with this mysql full-text query?

Tags: mysql, subquery, full-text-search

```
(SELECT COUNT(  `ad_general`.`id` ) as no
FROM (`ad_general`)
WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST (' +stack* 'IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `user` =  '1') 
) AS count
```

This query gives me this error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'AS count' at line 17

But this one is working as i expected.

```
SELECT COUNT(  `ad_general`.`id` ) as count
    FROM (`ad_general`)
    WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST (' +stack* 'IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `user` =  '1')
```

What's wrong with the first version ? I need it to work like in first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't name a query like that.  You can fix this by putting `select` in front:

```
select (SELECT COUNT(  `ad_general`.`id` ) as no
        FROM (`ad_general`)
        WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST (' +stack* 'IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `user` =  '1') 
       ) AS count
```

Or you could just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(  `ad_general`.`id` ) as `count`
FROM (`ad_general`)
WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST (' +stack* 'IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `user` =  '1')
```